# Is this the correct way of writing this expression in C++

Tags: c++

I work on a FEM solver Fenics with python. However, since python is a wrapper and the main programs are made in c++, I recently switched to the latter. I came across a demo with the following expressions (both code and expression shown below). I can't make sense of what's written and why would they write it like this. Is this something specific to the FEM platform I am using and should I look in that direction instead of considering this as an issue related to lack of knowledge in C++.

The Newmark beta time stepping scheme is being implemented where the acceleration update is defined by the expression:

a = 1/(2*beta)*((u - u0 - v0*dt)/(0.5*dt*dt) - (1-2*beta)*a0)

And is expressed in c++ code as:

```
// Acceleration update
void update_a(Function& a, const Function& u, const Function& a0,
              const Function& v0,  const Function& u0,
              double beta, double dt)
{
  *a.vector()  = *u.vector();
  *a.vector() -= *u0.vector();
  *a.vector() *= 1.0/dt;
  *a.vector() -= *v0.vector();
  *a.vector() *= 1.0/((0.5-beta)*dt);
  *a.vector() -= *a0.vector();
  *a.vector() *= (0.5-beta)/beta;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? And what is "this expression" in the title of question? "I can't make sense of what is written" is too broad for SO, in my opinion.

Comment: You should take a look at the type (class / struct) `Function`. It probably has a member function `vector` which returns a type with overloaded `operator*` or a pointer which when `*` is applied yields another type that supports the arithmetic and assignment expressions shown in your code.

Comment: Glancing at the code without knowing what it does, I would assume that objects of type `Function` actually stand for mathematical vectors somehow, `a.vector()` gets the vector, and operator overloading is used to carry out the ops in your expression. So `-= u0.vector()` subtracts `u0` in each position. The benefit of this might be, parallelizing / "vectorizing" the operations automatically or something? Or they just feel it is more clear this way.

Comment: Honestly I don't know why they wouldn't just iterate over the entries and compute a simple function in each place, that sounds faster then doing all this `.vector` stuff, but without you giving a complete code sample all I can do is speculate anyways.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Here is the complete code. http://fenicsproject.org/pub/archive/fenics-bzr-to-git-conversion-2013/repositories/bzr/dolfin.bzr/demo/undocumented/elastodynamics/cpp/main.cpp

Comment: @ChrisBeck: I think you're probably right. If those are indeed collections, the code would have 7 loops instead of 1.

Comment: @superuser, this is not really a question about the C++ language, this is a question about the FEM code base and what the definition of Function and its supporting classes are. You should probably look at their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in c++ generally you're looking to organise your code and data so that it's elegant (first) and performant (second, because this will follow from elegance).

This might be better:

```
double update_a(double u, double a0,
              double v0,  double u0,
              double beta, double dt)

// a = 1/(2*beta)*((u - u0 - v0*dt)/(0.5*dt*dt) - (1-2*beta)*a0)
{
  auto half_term = 1.0 / (2.0 * beta);
  auto v_increase_term = (u - u0 - v0 * dt) / (0.5 * dt * dt);
  auto drag_term = (1.0 - 2.0 * beta) * a0;

  return half_term * (v_increase_term - drag_term);

  /* or if you prefer...

  return (1.0 / (2.0 * beta))
    * ((u - u0 - v0 * dt) / (0.5 * dt * dt)
       - (1.0 - 2.0 * beta) * a0);
   */
}

// Velocity update
auto update_v(double a, double a0,
              double v0, double gamma, double dt)
{
  return dt * ((1.0 - gamma) * a0 + gamma * a) + v0;
}
```

You can then express this in terms of Function objects if you wish...

```
struct Function
{
  auto vector() -> double* { return std::addressof(_v); }
  auto vector() const -> const double* { return std::addressof(_v); }
  double _v = 0.0;
};

// Acceleration update
void update_a(Function& a, const Function& u, const Function& a0,
              const Function& v0,  const Function& u0,
              double beta, double dt)
{
  *a.vector() = update_a(*u.vector(), *a0.vector(), *v0.vector(), *u0.vector(),
                         beta, dt);
}
```

Comment: This is well done.  Good job abstracting away all those "fun" Function types.  It also fixes the math errors in OPs original attempt.